# Cannot find Operating System

Tags: installation

I cannot install Ubuntu on my Dell computer which has Windows ME installed. The copy works on my HP PC which has Windows XP installed.

When I try to install it in my Dell machine, it tells me that it cannot find an operating system and asks me to clean my hard drive. How do I install or make a Live Boot?

Comment: This probably means You installation media is broken. Try to re-download/re-burn it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a live session or just want to wipe Windows ME to install Ubuntu, there is nothing related to the current operating system. Just make sure you selected "Try Ubuntu without installing" when booting into your copy to get live session. Or just simply select "Renove all files and install Ubuntu" when installing to wipe out Windows ME and install Ubuntu.

However, if you want to dual-boot it might be difficult. Wubi doesn't support Windows ME now, and it makes sense for your copy not to support it. Windows ME is 13 years old now.